# Spring Boot ProGuard Embedded Tomcat Obfuscation

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, obfuscation

I'm not sure ProGuard is suited for this.
I've a Spring Boot app that I need to obfuscate. Using proguard-maven-plugin I reached a point where I have my code obfuscated. Anyway I had to repackage some jars because spring loader doesnt support compressed ones, but this is not the problem.
Something is wrong in the way the embedded tomcat start because i get this problem:

```
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed                                              
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springfram
ework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContaine
rFactory bean.
```

proguard-maven-plugin configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.foogroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <name>fooname</name>
    <description>foo description</description>
    <groupId>foogid</groupId>
    <artifactId>fooaid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Specify Java Compiler Version -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>

                    <options>
                        <option>-optimizations !class/marking/final</option>
                        <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents
                            **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/spring.*</option>
                        <option>-keepattributes
                            Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
                        <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static
                            void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
                        <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                            }
                        </option>
                        <option>-keep public class org.foo.**</option>
                        <option>-keep public class org.springframework.**</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                    <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.1</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I found some tips [here](http://midgetontoes.com/tips-for-using-proguard-with-spring-framework/) but doesnt mention anything about any issue with embedded servlet containers.

I suspect that i'm doing something wrong in the process and I cannot find any reliable working sample/tips on the web about this specific issue.

If you guys have suggestions on how to address this I'm all hears :)

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue now with spring boot, gradle and proguard. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue too.

In fact this issue was not caused by 'embedded servlet container'. I think it is because Proguard obfuscated some classes or interfaces before spring-boot repackage them. But somehow the classes / interfaces information(like name or path) in spring boot-info was not modified accordingly. Hence spring boot cannot initialize the beans and failed to startup the app.

I fixed it by simply add '-keepattributes xxx' into my proguard.conf file.

Since you already have '-keepattributes' in your configuration. I suggest you narrow the scope of protected files by using '-keep class !xxx', it might help you to find out the one who caused the issue.

My progard config:

```
-target 1.8
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontnote
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keep class !com.hbyuan27.demo.service.DemoService { *; }
#-keep class !com.hbyuan27.demo.**.service.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing the order of plugin, so first give the proguard plugin and then spring-boot-maven-plugin with repckage. For me this would works fine.